# Returning matplotlib fig with __repr__ or the like

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am building a Python class that is used to construct a matplotlib chart.  I've choosen to use a class because I want to be able to contruct the chart in a series of steps, rather than having a single function that takes a large number of arguments.

My primary work environment is Jupyter Lab and I generally have interactive plotting turned off, i.e., `plt.ioff()`.  Instead I like to use `display()` or display the figure implicitly by placing it on the last line of the cell.

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self):

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
```

Using the above example, I know I can do something like this

```
display(Example().fig)
```

But, I was hoping there was a way to make the `.fig` implicit, so that I can just do `display(Example())`.  I was originally thinking that I could do

```
def __repr__():
    return self.fig
```

But that approach seems not to work.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to show a png representation of the figure, so

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()

    def _repr_png_(self):
        return display(self.fig)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use `eval`.  Here's somethign that prints 'subplots' and returns a stirng values of zero.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        eval(self.__to_eval())
        return '0'

    def __to_eval(self):
        return "print('subplots')"
```

Example:

```
In [0]: Example()
subplots
Out[20]: 0
```